# Explicit bijection $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to P(\Bbb R) $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there any simple way to construct a bijective function: $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to P(\Bbb R) $ to see that $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is isomorphic to $P(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: I assume $P(\Bbb R)$ is the power set of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: This may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20016/bijection-between-2-mathbb-r-and-mathbb-r-r?rq=1

Comment: @pjs36 Correct!