# Bijection from $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{R})$ to the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, set-theory, real-numbers

I’m a bit confused as to how we get the bijection between a powerset of a set to the set of functions from that self to itself

I can see the obvious bijection from the powerset to the set ${[0,1]}^{R}$, but I’m missing the bijection from the set of these binary functions to the set of all real-valued functions

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20016/bijection-between-2-mathbb-r-and-mathbb-r-r?rq=1.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you - yes I somehow totally missed that one when searching, my bad. Thanks for the link!